# Parse a JSON feed

Tags: php, json, parsing, feed

I'm having trouble retrieving "name","att","cmp", and "yds" in this NFL Game Center JSON feed. Using PHP.

How can I retrieve these values without hard-coding "2015091700" and "00-0023436"?

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/game-center/2015091700/2015091700_gtd.json

```
{  
"2015091700":{  
  "home":{  
     "stats":{  
        "passing":{  
           "00-0023436":{  
              "name":"A.Smith",
              "att":25,
              "cmp":16,
              "yds":191
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

This is the code I have right now.

```
$url  = file_get_contents("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/game-center/2015091700/2015091700_gtd.json");
$json = json_decode($url, true); // 'true' makes data an array
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($json)); 
$player = array();

foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
  $player[$key] = $value;
  echo $player['name'];
}
```

This is close to what I need. However, the page spits out:

```
A.Smith 
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
J.Charles
J.Charles
J.Charles
J.Charles
J.Charles
J.Charles
J.Charles
J.Charles
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
A.Smith
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting duplicate values. How do I make this reflect what the JSON feed has? I'd ideally like to create a query string that I can insert into my MySQL database table.

Comment: I've updated my question to include some code I've tried.

Comment: Modifying the question to look for a different solution is just *bad* practice.

Comment: *Hath that a Stealth edit I see before me Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is by using PHP's [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class which allows you to iterate through any of the other iterator classes and the [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) class which allows easy iteration through an array. These are part of PHP's [SPL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php). You can use it like this:

```
<?php
$data = '{
"2015091700":{  
  "home":{  
     "stats":{  
        "passing":{  
           "00-0023436":{  
              "name":"A.Smith",
              "att":25,
              "cmp":16,
              "yds":191
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
}';

$json = json_decode($data, true); // 'true' makes data an array

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($json)); 

foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key .' '. $value . '<br />';
}

?>
```

The result is:

```
name A.Smith
att 25
cmp 16
yds 191
```

[EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/cxp7-sd2v)

If you want to get individual bits into variables the easiest way it to make a small change to the code:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($json)); 

$player = array();

foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    $player[$key] = $value;

}
echo $player['name'];
```

This allows you to describe a player and assign the keys properly to the player. The result of the above would be:

```
A.Smith
```

Now you can use the various parts of the player's data as you need as they are readily identified by their keys.

Comment: This is accessing the data. Thank you. Could you elaborate on the answer and add a solution for assigning the name, att, cmp, and yds values as variables? Maybe there's a better way then doing if $key == 'name' then $name = $value

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting duplicate values now. Can you look at my updated question?

Comment: It is because each of those players appears multiple times in the JSON.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the duplicates?

Comment: I would have to spend some time with the feed to come up with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Decode the JSON as an associative array, then loop over it with `foreach`.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
    // $key = 2015091700
    // $val = an associative array with one row.
    // ['home' => ... ]
}
```

Comment: That does help. How do I echo out the name, att, cmp, etc. values with this?

Comment: You'll need to drill down into that array: `foreach($val['home']['stats']['passing'] as $key2=>$val2){}`.  Where `$key2` is `00-0023436` and `$val2` is an array you can loop over: `foreach($val2 as $key3=>$val3){}`.  Yes, there's a lot of `foreach`es, it's a deep nested array.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$decoded = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($decoded['2015091700']);
```